# customer Id not return in shopify cart webhook

Tags: shopify

The Shopify cart webhook is not returning customer id. so we can't able to identify which user added the product to cart.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't get the customer id from that webhook and the point is that a cart can be created by a registered customer or an unregistered customer as well so in this last case Shopify doesn't know the customer id yet.

Also the example response included in the [documentation](https://help.shopify.com/api/reference/webhook) doesn't include the customer id.

```
 {
  "id": "eeafa272cebfd4b22385bc4b645e762c",
  "token": "eeafa272cebfd4b22385bc4b645e762c",
  "line_items": [
    {
      "id": 1234567,
      "properties": {
      },
      "quantity": 3,
      "variant_id": 1234567,
      "key": "1234567:f816dcc3b2e26822a28626a786eac953",
      "title": "Example T-Shirt - ",
      "price": "19.99",
      "original_price": "19.99",
      "discounted_price": "19.99",
      "line_price": "59.97",
      "original_line_price": "59.97",
      "total_discount": "0.00",
      "discounts": [
      ],
      "sku": "example-shirt-s",
      "grams": 200,
      "vendor": "Acme",
      "product_id": 327475578523353102,
      "gift_card": false
    }
  ]
}
```

You can probably get the customer id using the checkout webhook but without knowing your requirements I can't say this will work for you.

I recommend you to open another question and provide more information on your requirement.

Comment: My requirement is that, when the customer clicks on add to cart, I need to track the user and cart info. it is like user activity track events like that.
So without customer id, I cant able to recognize, which user added the product in cart event.

Comment: Another solution is not to use webhooks at all but use liquid and JS. So in your theme you can get the customer id using liquid -> customer.id, note that customer can be null if the user is not logged in. 

After something is added to the cart you can call your own api using Ajax. You should look for a way to get the events in JS.

You can also use Shopify Proxy Apps to call your API using the same domain as your store. 

But you also should consider the security details of this solution, this is very important.

Comment: Thank you for your solution